# How do you center a div with Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, center, centering

i have trouble with internet explorer and centering , my question is how can i centering a div without the CENTER tag
and it got to work in all the browsers ,
because i was using

```
margin:auto;
```

it works in all borwsers
but it does not work in internet explorer
i'm looking for something that will work in all the browsers
someone told me to put

```
text-align: center;
```

to the body but than all the text has go to the middle

so how can i do that?

Comment: margin:auto should work if the width is specified

Comment: `margin:0 auto` can also work with some [shrink wrapping techniques](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Shrink-Wrap) for divs without specified widths.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're close. Use the CSS below:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/WBPDk/). Note that I gave the div a fixed width.

Answer (score 2):

IE has spotty support for auto margins (i.e., different behavior in quirks mode).  This should work in pretty much all cases though:

CSS:

```
.container {
    /* for IE */
    text-align: center;
}
#the-div {
    /* reset text-align */
    text-align: left;
    /* for "good" browsers */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="the-div">centered content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome :) Guess you figured out that my `//` comments were busted before i did though lol. Fixing now...

Comment: You can get rid of the container div if you use the body as the container.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a width as well as margin:

```
div.center { width:980px; margin:0px auto; }
```

Example HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="center">CONTENT</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works perfectly in IE.

```
.container {
    /* for IE */
    text-align: center;
}
#the-div {
    /* reset text-align */
    text-align: left;
    /* for "good" browsers */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is close, the your issue isn't the browser. The simple fix is to change the inner div class.

You have your position absolute with Left 25%... Use Left 50% and it will autocorrect.

Remove the left: 50% entirely and add margin: 0 auto; as previously noted on another answer.